# Can't execute this read statements correctly?

Tags: command-line, bash

```
Read a b c 
Echo $a $b $ c
```

It takes only value of `a`. What should I do , so that my first code may be run properly?

Comment: Run `read a; read b; read c` instead. `read` can only take one argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should give it three values separated by spaces:

```
echo 1 2 3 | read a b c; echo $a; echo $b; echo $c
1
2
3
```

Comment: Won't work: to execute `echo 1 2 3 | read a b c` Bash forks a subshell, so the values will be set correctly in the subshell, but they won't be visible by the `echo` statements. `<<<'1 2 3' read a b c` won't fork a subshell, so `a` `b` and `c` will be set in the current shell.

Comment: Oh, yes. I use zsh and it executes the last command in a pipe in the current shell. So it worked for me.  But not for bash or sh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass values like this:

```
$ read a b c
1 2 3
$ echo $a $b $c
1 2 3
```

This way its working fine. You just have to pass values separated by space.

Answer (score 0):

From `help read`:

```
    Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
    if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
    splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
    word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
    the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
    delimiters.
```

So `read` willl read one line from STDIN and split it on the characters contained in `$IFS`, assigning each field to each NAME and potential excessive fields to the last NAME.

`$IFS` by default contains a space, a tabulation and a newline, so by default `read` will split its input each time a space or a tabulation is found (the newline by default is used by `read` to split records, so it will be used to split records rather then to split fields, even if a newline is contained in `$IFS`).

So you should set `$IFS` based on how you want to split the input.

Assuming that you want to store space-separated values (and hence splitting the input on the characters contained in `$IFS` by default is fine), you should do something like this:

```bsh
read a b c
echo $a $b $c
```

```bsh
$ read a b c
aaa bbb ccc
$ echo $a $b $c
aaa bbb ccc
$ echo $a
aaa
$ echo $b
bbb
$ echo $c
ccc
```

If you want to store e.g. comma-separated values, set `$IFS` to `,` for the scope of `read`'s execution:

```bsh
IFS=, read a b c
echo $a $b $c
```

```bsh
$ IFS=, read a b c
aaa,bbb,ccc
$ echo $a $b $c
aaa bbb ccc
$ echo $a
aaa
$ echo $b
bbb
$ echo $c
ccc
```

If you want to store newline-separated values (or if you want to input each value separating it from the next one using an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keystroke for that matter), you'll have to read the input three times:

```bsh
read a
read b
read c
echo $a $b $c
```

```bsh
$ read a
aaa
$ read b
bbb
$ read c
ccc
$ echo $a $b $c
aaa bbb ccc
$ echo $a
aaa
$ echo $b
bbb
$ echo $c
ccc
```